# Resaving camera roll images are smaller

Tags: ios, iphone

When I resave an image from camera roll, it is smaller than the original one :
same number of pixels, same width and height, same colorspace, same DPI,

but file size is less : 
original = 2.5 MB
resaved one = 1.5 MB

I use this method :
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageTosave, self, nil, nil);

Is this normal ?

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue a while agoitand found a workaround. Try wrapping the image in a new png:

```
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (yourOriginalImage); // get PNG representation
UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2, nil, nil, nil); // save to photo album
```

Please let me know if this workaround still works. If not, I will remove this answer.

Comment: well, the file size went up to 13.8 MB. But is it normal that with same number of pixels and same colorspace, the file size changes ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the file was jpg and is now larger because it is saved with png, which has a lower compression rate. What happens if you try the same procedure with UIImageJPGRepresentation?

Comment: well, this time it is downsizing to 1.6 MB ...and indeed it was a jpg image. I can assume that jpg is always compressing images so that is why it takes less place on disk, but with same number of pixels and same colorspace ???